# Unable to Install InstantObjects

Tags: delphi, instantobjects

When I try to install InstantObjects from the GetIt Package Manager, I get:

> E2202 Required package 'FireDACODBCDriver not found

I have Delphi 11.3, Patch 1 on Windows 10.

What do I need to install?

Comment: Which edition of Delphi do you have? FireDAC ODBC driver is included only in Architect or Enterprise editions but not in Professional or Community editions. To learn more check [RAD STUDIO 11.3 PRODUCT FEATURE MATRIX](https://dtffvb2501i0o.cloudfront.net/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf)

Comment: I have the professional edition.  So I guess I can't use InstantObjects unless I upgrade.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably contact InstantObject developers to see if they might be able to make it compatible with Professional Edition of Delphi. You have nothing to lose.

Comment: I contacted the developers.  They did not respond.